# Dagger 2 component keeping old reference

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

### Background

I have multiple dagger scopes in the app

- **UserScope** - scope representing user session
- **ActivityScope** - scope per activity
- **UserComponent** - sub component of CoreComponent
- **UserManager** - singleton that creates UserComponent
- **HomeComponent** - Component that is dependent on UserComponent

### Issue

I am trying to update user object under `UserScope` but somehow the object update doesn't get reflected on it's dependent components. So, once update screen updates the user object and the activity in backstack receives the event for the update & I want to reflect that update in my dagger dependencies.
I tried to null the existing component inside `UserManager` but it looks like the dependent components still holds it's reference.

#### Summary

1. User logs in and opens Home screen. At this moment my user manager has created user component with the user object obtained from API call.
2. Home screen opens update screen which updates the user by re-creating new `userComponent` inside `UserManager`. This also fires an event which tells home screen to fetch the updated user object.
3. Home screen receives the event. However, HomeViewModel(Screen in backstack) is still referring to old `User` object injected by dagger.

#### Questions

- Is this because `HomeComponent` is an independant component? So, it keeps an old reference?
- Is there any way to achieve this update?

  - Preferably without using `SubComponent`. Because I am using a multi-module(dynamic-feature) setup that helps me if I treat this as a separate component.

#### CoreComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component
interface CoreComponent {

    val userBuilder: UserComponent.Builder

    val userManager: UserManager

    fun providerContext(): Context

    fun inject(activity: UserActivity)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(
            @BindsInstance applicationContext: Context
        ): CoreComponent
    }
}
```

#### UserComponent

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent
interface UserComponent {

    val userManager: UserManager

    @UserScope
    val user: User

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {

        fun bindUser(@BindsInstance user: User): Builder
        fun build(): UserComponent
    }
}
```

#### UserManager

```
@Singleton
class UserManager @Inject constructor(private val userBuilder: UserComponent.Builder) {

    var userComponent: UserComponent? = null
        private set

    init {
        // creating as a dummy reference
        createUser(User("1", "1"))
    }

    fun createUser(user: User) {
        userComponent = null
        userComponent = userBuilder.bindUser(user).build()
    }

    fun logout() {
        userComponent = null
    }
}
```

#### HomeComponent

```
@Component(
    modules = [HomeModule::class],
    dependencies = [UserComponent::class]
)
@ActivityScope
interface HomeComponent {

    fun inject(activity: HomeActivity)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(
            @BindsInstance applicationContext: HomeActivity,
            coreComponent: UserComponent,
        ): HomeComponent
    }
}
```

#### HomeModule

```
@Module
class HomeModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    fun provideVM(activity: HomeActivity, user: User): HomeViewModel {
        val vm by activity.scopedComponent {
            HomeViewModel(user)
        }
        return vm
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have components `A -> B -> C` and decide to swap `B` for `B*` then you also need to get rid of any object that was created by/using `B` or anything that depends on `B`, so any subcomponents, component dependencies, objects, etc.

In this example you'd recreate `C` as well (using `B*` this time) to get a `C*` (using the new dependencies). Now you have new components `A -> B* -> C*`, but your code (Activity/Fragment/ViewModel) that was created using `B/C` needs to be "updated" as well. Since it's not feasible to "update" dependencies later, the easiest way to do this would be to recreate all of them as well, this time using `B*/C*` for injection.

**e.g.**
In one app where I allow switching between users, I have my main Activity "Singleton -> Activity" scoped, referencing the user manager and displaying the switch UI. The actual app content (per user) is wrapped in a `UserFragment` which I'll replace as a whole whenever the user changes since this fragment (and all the UI within it) is `Singleton -> Activity -> User -> Fragment` scoped.
Since Singleton including the user manager won't change, I don't have to recreate the Activity, so all I need to do is recreate the parts affected (in my case the Fragment).